# Java Xpath change root element name

Tags: java, xpath

Is there any way to update the root element name but the values of the child should be the same using Xpath java ?? for eg

```
    <root>
     <child1>value</child1>
     <child2>value2</child2>
    </root>
```

to

```
    <newRoot>
     <child1>value</child1>
     <child2>value2</child2>
    </newRoot>
```

Comment: XPath is a query language. You cannot use it to change data.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I am new to use Xpath also I would like to know if there is any way to select all the elements except the root element?

Comment: Select the root, then get its children.

Answer (score 0):

XPath can only select complete subtrees, not modify them. If you need to change elements, either

- Use XPath to select subelements and other APIs like DOM to modify them. For example, you could select the node using `/root` and then apply some function to rename it.
- Use XQuery, which is a superset of XPath and able to modify documents using its XQuery Update extension. There is a bunch of XQuery implementations with Java APIs, for example Saxon, BaseX, Sedna, ... An XQuery Update statement for this would be `rename node /root as 'newRoot'`.